# ResourceJS: Creating nested REST interface w/ Mongoose Schema + child subdocument?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, mongoose

**UPDATE**

I have narrowed down the issue to the main problem:

The example code in [Nested Resources with ResourceJS](https://github.com/travist/resourcejs#nested-resources), takes two Mongoose Schemas, PARENT and CHILD, & creates these REST resources:

```
/parent - (GET), (POST)
/parent/:parentId - (GET), (PUT), (DELETE)
/parent/:parentId/child - (GET), (POST)
/parent/:parentId/child/:childId - (GET), (PUT), (DELETE)
```

PARENT and CHILD are 2 models; one declared the parent of the other:

```
var Parent = mongoose.model('Parent', new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
}));

var Child = mongoose.model('Child', new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  parent: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Parent',
    index: true,
    required: true
  }
}));
```

**However**, we are trying to achieve this with an embedded document:

**models/MyModel.js**

```
var ChildSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  // variables and ID

}, { collection: 'child' });

var ParentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  // variables and ID
  children: [ChildSchema]

}, { collection: 'parent'});

module.exports = mongoose.model('parent', ParentSchema);
```

ResourceJS creates REST interfaces with this function:

```
Resource(app, route, name, model);
```

Where:

- **app** is the Express application.
- **route** is the route to "mount" this resource onto. In nested resources, this could be '/parent/:parentId'
- **name** - The name of the resource used for the URL path of that resource.
- **model** - The interface’s Mongoose Model.

We would like to get something like **app.models.parent.child** in the *model* parameter to make the child REST interface, or something like that:

```
Resource(app, '/child/:childId', 'child', app.models.parent.child).rest({    
  // the before handler code
});
```

Obviously, this does not work. For CHILD, I am not sure of what kind of object type I am feeding in the *model* parameter, v.s. what it actually asks for.

parent/:parentId/child (GET) returns an [ ]

parent/:parentId/child/:childId (GET) returns this error:

> {"status":404,"errors":["Resource not found"]}

Our code:

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var _ = require('lodash');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override'));

app.use(function(req, res, next) { // CORS Support
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();
});

app.models = module.exports = {
  parent: require('./models/MyModel')
  // should Child be declared ?
};

var Resource = require('resourcejs');

// The parent REST interface.
Resource(app, '', 'parent', app.models.parent).rest();

// The child REST interface.
Resource(app, '/parent/:parentId', 'child', app.models.learn.child).rest({
// ResourceJS seems to append 'Id' to 'parent' var above

  // before handler, include filter and parent info
  before: function(req, res, next) {
    req.body.parent = req.params.parentId;
    req.modelQuery = this.model.where('parent', req.params.parentId);
    next();
  }
});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myApp');
mongoose.connection.once('open', function() {
  app.listen(3000);
});
```

**Specs:**

All the dependencies are up to date and mirror what is shown in the ResourceJS JSON package:
"express": "^4.14.0",
"fast-json-patch": "^0.5.7",
"lodash": "^4.17.4",
"mongodb": "^2.2.16",
"mongoose": "^4.7.5"

**THIS IS THE RESOURCEJS EXAMPLE CODE**

```
// The parent REST interface.
Resource(app, '', 'parent', Parent).rest();

// The child REST interface.
Resource(app, '/parent/:parentId', 'child', Child).rest({

  // Add a before handler to include filter and parent information.
  before: function(req, res, next) {
    req.body.parent = req.params.parentId;
    req.modelQuery = this.model.where('parent', req.params.parentId);
    next();
  }
});
```